# Как изменить высоту layout в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, framelayout

Вывел на экран RecyclerView на элементе которого присутствует ImageView.
Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на это ImageView данный элемент RecyclerView изменял свою высоту (было 70dp - стало 30dp)
Это макет для элемента RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/containerMy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">
    <!--буду слушать нажатия на этот ImageView-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_outline_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.521" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

В адаптере определяю нужные объекты

```
private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout; // ссылка на корневой Layout
private FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;
constraintLayout =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.containerMy);
```

На ImageView вешаю слушатель для обработки клика:

```
params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,pxToDp(35));
constraintLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Но при выполнении кода обработки слушателя получаю ошибку:
"android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams"
Подскажите, как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Быстрым вариантом фикса будет оборачивание вашей разметки элемента списка во FrameLayout.

Comment: Завернул весь макет (вместе с ConstreintLayout) во FrameLayout. Вообще ничего не поменялось. Ошибка та же самая осталась

Comment: privat FrameLayout frameLayout;                      private FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;      frameLayout =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.containerFrame);                                    frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: Я не советовал вам вещать ID на FrameLayout, находить его и ему менять параметры. Оставьте код как в вопросе и оберните разметку, как в первом комменте написано - должно заработать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо. Теперь всё работает как требовалось.